# applying an operation to multiple columns having multiple columns in the result

Tags: python, pandas

in sql the query would look like `select id, avg(x), avg(y), max(x), max(y) from table group by id`
can it be transformed into a single operation on pandas data frame?
I can get each function result like

```
mydf['center_x'] =  mydf.groupby('id')['x'].mean()
mydf['center_y'] =  mydf.groupby('id')['y'].mean()
```

etc

but it's excessive call of the same operation, plus excessive storage demand (mydf is huge). Besides it's kind of troublesome to get the unique set at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: `agg` is definitely the answer but regarding your last statement: you can save a groupby object (`g = df.groupby('id')`) and then call functions when needed (`g['x'].mean()` etc.), you don't need to group every time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is supported, see the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once).

To cite from there:

```
In [56]: grouped = df.groupby('A')

In [57]: grouped['C'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std])
Out[57]: 
          sum      mean       std
A                                
bar  0.443469  0.147823  0.301765
foo  2.529056  0.505811  0.966450
```

Maybe more pertinent to your questions, you can also do different functions for different columns like so:

```
In [60]: grouped.agg({'C' : np.sum,
   ....:              'D' : lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1)})
   ....: 
Out[60]: 
            C         D
A                      
bar  0.443469  1.490982
foo  2.529056  0.645875
```

Or, a practical example even closer to your original questions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"group":list("aaaaabbbbb"), "A":np.random.rand(10), "B":np.random.rand(10)})
df.groupby("group").agg({"A":[np.sum, np.mean], "B":[np.sum, np.mean]})


    A               B
    sum     mean    sum     mean
group               
a   1.450488    0.290098    3.526962    0.705392
b   1.570386    0.314077    2.734465    0.546893
```

Comment: thanks, Nils, looks like one can combine multiple functions applied to the same column. But for x and y of the original example I still need two selects and then join them or can it be just one?

Comment: Not sure I understand - isn't that what the second example does? I.e. apply a function to column `C`, and one to column `D`?

Comment: is it possible to have 2 functions on column C and 2 on column D? Is it possible to make a combo of 2 your examples? average and max for one column and average and max for another. In your second example 'C' and 'D' going to be both input and output columns or they has to be somehow renamed on output

Comment: Ah, got you - added another example that hopefully does what you're looking for. Hope this finally answers the question! :)